# Generate strings using translations of several characters, mapped to several others

Tags: python

I'm facing quite a tricky problem in my python code. I looked around and was not able to find anyone with a similar problem.

I'd like to generate strings translating some characters into several, different ones.

I'd like that original characters, meant to be replaced (translated), to be replaced by several different ones.
What I'm looking to do is something like this :

```
text = "hi there"
translations = {"i":["b", "c"], "r":["e","f"]}
result = magicfunctionHere(text,translations)
print(result)
> [
    "hb there",
    "hc there",
    "hi theee",
    "hi thefe",
    "hb theee",
    "hb thefe",
    "hc theee",
    "hc thefe"
]
```

The result contains any combination of the original text with 'i' and 'r' replaced respectively by 'b' and 'c', and 'e' and 'f'.

I don't see how to do that, using itertools and functions like permutations, product etc...

I hope I'm clear enough, it is quite a specific problem !
Thank you for your help !

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  Have you studied recursion, stacks, and/or graph searching?  How did you generate the expected results?  Think about how you did that, be precise about it, and then try to write it in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def magicfunction(ret, text, alphabet_location, translations):
    if len(alphabet_location) == 0:
        ret.append(text)
        return ret
    index = alphabet_location.pop()
    for w in translations[text[index]]:
        ret = magicfunction(ret, text[:index] + w + text[index + 1:], alphabet_location, translations)
    alphabet_location.append(index)
    return ret

def magicfunctionHere(text, translations):
    alphabet_location = []
    for key in translations.keys():
        alphabet_location.append(text.find(key))
        translations[key].append(key)
    ret = []
    ret = magicfunction(ret, text, alphabet_location, translations)
    ret.pop()
    return ret

text = "hi there"
translations = {"i":["b", "c"], "r":["e","f"]}
result = magicfunctionHere(text,translations)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

One crude way to go would be to use a `Nested Loop Construct`in 2 steps *(Functions)* as depicted in the Snippet below:

```
def rearrange_characters(str_text, dict_translations):
    tmp_result = []
    for key, value in dict_translations.items():
        if key in str_text:
            for replacer in value:
                str_temp = str_text.replace(key, replacer, 1)
                if str_temp not in tmp_result:
                    tmp_result.append(str_temp)
    return tmp_result


def get_rearranged_characters(str_text, dict_translations):
    lst_result = rearrange_characters(str_text, dict_translations)
    str_joined = ','.join(lst_result)
    for str_part in lst_result:
        str_joined = "{},{}".format(str_joined, ','.join(rearrange_characters(str_part, dict_translations)))
    return set(str_joined.split(sep=","))


text            = "hi there"
translations    = {"i": ["b", "c"], "r":["e","f"]}
result          = get_rearranged_characters(text, translations)
print(result)
## YIELDS: {
            'hb theee', 
            'hc thefe', 
            'hc there', 
            'hi thefe', 
            'hb thefe', 
            'hi theee', 
            'hc theee', 
            'hb there'
            }
```

[image]

See also: https://eval.in/960803


Another equally convoluted approach would be to use a single function with nested loops like so:

```
def process_char_replacement(str_text, dict_translations):
    tmp_result = []
    for key, value in dict_translations.items():
        if key in str_text:
            for replacer in value:
                str_temp = str_text.replace(key, replacer, 1)
                if str_temp not in tmp_result:
                    tmp_result.append(str_temp)

    str_joined = ','.join(tmp_result)
    for str_part in tmp_result:
        tmp_result_2 = []
        for key, value in dict_translations.items():
            if key in str_part:
                for replacer in value:
                    str_temp = str_part.replace(key, replacer, 1)
                    if str_temp not in tmp_result_2:
                        tmp_result_2.append(str_temp)
        str_joined = "{},{}".format(str_joined, ','.join(tmp_result_2))
    return set(str_joined.split(sep=","))


text            = "hi there"
translations    = {"i": ["b", "c"], "r":["e","f"]}      
result          = process_char_replacement(text, translations)
print(result)
## YIELDS: {
            'hb theee', 
            'hc thefe', 
            'hc there', 
            'hi thefe', 
            'hb thefe', 
            'hi theee', 
            'hc theee', 
            'hb there'
            }
```

Refer to: https://eval.in/961602